# I want to know how to use livedata and viewModel instead of CursorLoader and other Loader classes?

Tags: viewmodel, android-livedata, loader, android-cursorloader

I am new to android and the tutorials i watched to solve the loader is that they say use CursorLoader while using content provider but when i went to developer site they say CursorLoader is deprecated and Loader classes are also deprecated. They suggest to use LiveData and ViewModel instead but i have no idea to implement this.

consider i want to retrive data from a content provider using LiveData and ViewModel. Is it possible to do so and if please help. Thank you